# tikz picture: unit instead of penultimate number of the axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphs, units, axis

Is there a way to insert the unit instead of the penultimate number of the axis like this?

0 1 2 3 m 5

Thats something my university wants to see in my Bachelor thesis...
But after searching through the tikz manual still no idea...

Code so far:

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        [xmin=0, xmax=5, ymin=0, ymax=200, xtick align=outside, 
        ytick align=outside, xtick pos=left, ytick pos=left, 
        minor tick num=5, xlabel=Flächenintensität, ylabel=Schmelzbadtiefe,
        xtick={1,2,3,m,5}]
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Obviously it doesn't work this way, because I have to insert a number, but how do I do it right?

Can someone pls help me :)

thank you in advance

Comment: Do you want to replace 5 or 4 with m? Please clarify, both your examples do different things

Comment: Maybe help : https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19777/31034

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
xticklabels={0,1,2,3,m,5}
```

was the command I couldn't find. Use as an option to the `axis` environment.